# Google Analytics tracking both of my website versions after template migration

Tags: google-analytics

GoDaddy migrated my Wordpress template from one website (hosted by HostMonster) to a new website.

GoDaddy set up Google Analytics on new website. Old website remains in use. Both use the same template with some changes on the new website. Old website is pulling Google Analytics data from the new one.

I’m at a loss (so is GoDaddy) and desperate to fix this as old website will continue and is messing with their Google Analytics statistics.

Any ideas why the old website's Google Analytics is tracking the new one?

Comment: Hi, did you find out what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only way this is happening is that you have the same Google Analytics Account and Property installed in both sites. To find this out, check the **source code** of both sites and look for the Google analytics `<script>` tags and find if ID after **UA**-XXXXX-YY is the same for both sites.

If this is the case, you would like to keep the same GA account, create a new property and assign that new property to the New site. This will allow you to keep tracking separately both sites in two different properties within the same GA account.

[image]